# Is my 1D signal using CNN & RNN regression reasonable?

Tags: time-series, conv-neural-network, signal-processing, recurrent-neural-network

I want to know if my impact-echo signals are proper with CNN or RNN regression model.

I got some simulated signal, as following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ9fO.jpg) shows.

In previous research, people mostly consider frequency or even time-frequency analysis. For deeper crack the signal response lower frequency [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdQUZ.jpg).

Singal input are their 1D signal, and want output present their depths. But my train simulated crack are all create integer (e.g. 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26), so I'm wondering if these signals in time domain using CNN [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dayRZ.jpg) or RNN [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zahzb.jpg) model do regression task is reasonable. (Is my RNN model wrong or BIG concept misleading)

And I hope the model can learn (e.g. train 10cm and 12cm depth crack signal, when the model input is a 11cm signal it can be predict as 11).

Also if it is reasonable, which paper should I read or some paper related to enhance knowledge.

If the question is not clearly describe, please told me (I'm not native in English). Thank you guys.

Comment: Your question is a better fit for the [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).